# Specify same package id for all home widgets in Flutter Home Widget

Tags: android, flutter, widget

I am trying to create widget in Flutter using the Flutter home package.
https://pub.dev/packages/home_widget

I could successfully do it in iOS.

But when done for Android, I get the following error because of different build variants.

```
Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(-3, No Widget found with Name HomeWidgetExampleProvider. Argument 'name' must be the same as your AppWidgetProvider you wish to update, java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.myappvariant.HomeWidgetExampleProvider.
```

How can I make only one class for all the build variants and keep the same id for the Home Widget.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
HomeWidget.updateWidget(qualifiedAndroidName: 'com.yourappvariant.HomeWidgetExampleProvider');
```

Here may be a hint.
https://github.com/ABausG/home_widget/blob/main/android/src/main/kotlin/es/antonborri/home_widget/HomeWidgetPlugin.kt#L79-L93